# Text box seems to always open vertically by default in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, debug

I bought a new laptop with Windows10 and it hasPowerpoint 2016 installed on it.

Whenever I add a text box the text starts typing vertically. How do I fix it?

[image]

I mean, if I drag the box wider that does fix it. But I must do it manually each time. I tried, "set as default text box" after dragging it to make it wider. But that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Just for reference I've shown the wrong (by default) and right box widths below.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (instructions based on PowerPoint 2016):

- Right-click one text box and choose "Format Shape..."
- In the Format Shape pane, click "Size & Properties"
- Open the "Text Box" branch
- Set "Text direction" to "Horizontal"
- Right-click again the text box and choose "Set as Default Text Box".
  Ensure that the dimensions of the used box are suitable as default sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Harrymc:  That did not work. :(

Curious_cat:  I did a bit of digging as I kept having the same issue.  Open Format Shape-->Size and Properties-->Text Box window.  When that window opens, at the bottom there is a button for "Wrap text in shape".  Deselect it.  That worked for me.  Then do what Harrymc suggested and make it the default text box as he described.  Not sure why that wrap text is a default choice.

OK, so when I closed and opened PPT the fix above did not save.  I then went into the Shape Format menu at the top of the PPT window.  When in that menu, to the far left you'll see the text box choice there.  Select it and put a new text box on a PPT slide.  Then follow the instructions above.  This seemed to finally set it as the default.  It has seemed to work for me.  Sorry if it does not fix your trouble.